# Windows 10 tells me no ethernet connection when I am connected to the internet via ethernet

Tags: ethernet, network-adapter, sony-vaio, windows-10-v1511

My laptop: [Sony VAIO SVT15117CDS](https://esupport.sony.com/CA/p/model-home.pl?mdl=SVT15117CDS)

My OS: Windows 10 Home 64-bit (version 1511 build 10586.36)

I hooked up an ethernet cable to my laptop, and internet is working on my computer without problems.

[image]

However, Windows 10 incorrectly tells me that I am not connected to the internet.
[image]
[image]

I have reinstalled my network adapter driver, restarted my computer, and went through the Windows Network Diagnostics wizard which couldn't identify any problems.

**UPDATE:**
So the problem went away for a few weeks and now it's back. Windows tells me there is no ethernet connection (as described above), yet I am using the ethernet connection without problem.

Network Connection Details:
[image]

Comment: Do you have to use a proxy? Please provide a screenshot of the Ethernet connection’s Status → Details view.

Comment: Its a windows bug, mt W7 pc did that last year but suddenly stopped it after a month. I ignored it.

Comment: @Moab Indeed, this seems to be a bug. After a regular system reboot the problem seems to have gone away! If this issue comes back, I will post back here with more details.

Comment: @DanielB I am not using a proxy. I have added a screenshot of the connection details.